# Pure CSS speech bubble with triangles: Firefox renders ugly 1px border for no reason?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to do a simple speech bubble using the border triangle technique, by overlaying two triangles, one with the border color I want and the other one with the background color of the speech bubble, using :before and :after pseudo classes:

[Here's a JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wildmind_ch/JJ3uk/1/)

```
.bubble:before, .bubble:after {
    border-style: solid;    
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.bubble:before {
    border-color: #DCDCDC transparent;
    border-width: 33px 0 0 33px;
    bottom: -33px;
    left: 40px;
}
.bubble:after {
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    border-width: 35px 0 0 35px;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: 37px;
}
```

The problem is the .bubble:after triangle. For some reason Firefox on Windows 8 renders an additional border that I have not defined, which looks really bad.

[image]

It works jolly well on Chrome and even Internet Explorer 10, 9 and 8 displays this perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add

```
border-style: outset;
```

**Update**
To make it more visible on FF

```
border-style: solid outset;
```

To your

```
.bubble:before, .bubble:after {
```

(Updated JSFiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/bFFrK/1

Comment: That makes the additional border dissapear allright, but now I can practically not see the dent at all anymore (in FF). Chrome and IE continue to display well. Heres a link to the thing in my project, left FF and right Chrome. http://i.imgur.com/NeavY9p.png

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much. Funny, I had border-style:solid in there, but as a distinct attribute at the beginning. Anyway, works like a charm now.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner Wow! I just realized what you meant. You're right! you do have a `border-style: solid;` at the beginning. I don't know why that didn't work well will the `border-style: outset;`

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, I'm thinking of two quick suggestions to try. I'm not running Windows 8, so I can't try these myself, but why not try these before we get too involved:

First one is adding the `-moz` prefix and duplicating some of the border styles:

```
.bubble:after {
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
border-width: 35px 0 0 35px;
-moz-border-width: 35px 0 0 35px;
bottom: -30px;
left: 37px;
}
```

That's just a quick thing to try out.

If that's not working, you should try adding `border-style: outset;` to the `.bubble` class (both `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes). I would also throw in `z-index` values, to make the triangles slightly more compatible.

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JJ3uk/2/

And if you want to make your life easier when creating CSS triangles, I stumbled across this great CSS triangle generator. It even includes options for backwards compatibility all the way back to IE6, if you're interested. It seems to be the best one around:

[CSS triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Let me/us know if this solves the problem, or if something else does.

**EDIT**

You may also need to manually set the RGB values of the borders of the triangle, rather than just using transparent, since the `border-style: outset` may change the colour of the border in FF17.

```
border-color: rgba( RED-VALUE, GREEN_VALUE , BLUE-VALUE, 0) rgba(RED-VALUE, GREEN-VALUE,  BLUE-VALUE, 0) rgba(RED-VALUE, GREEN-VALUE, BLUE-VALUE, 0) #ffffff;
```

Comment: Solved, see above answer by Timber232. border-style: solid outset; did the trick.